# How to match column value from right using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch value from table by matching string from right. Here is my table:

db_user:

```
id        mobile   

1        9937229858

2        9937229867
```

Here I have this value `$mob=+919937229858` and I need to search from table. Here I need query to search from right if any column value `i.e-9937229858` is matched with `$mob=+919937229858` from right then that row will be fetched. Here as per value the first row value will be fetched.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are not a code writing service. A hint: `WHERE mobile = ...`.

Comment: Tip: `like '%lookup'`

Comment: I am doing like this `SELECT * 
FROM  `db_user` 
WHERE mobile LIKE  '%+919937229858'` but not coming.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE mobile REGEXP '$mob'` I am using this and working good for me so you can try it.

Comment: I am doing like `SELECT * 
FROM  `db_user` 
WHERE mobile REGEXP  '+919937229858'` but its throwing error.

Comment: *`Here I have this value $mob=+919937229858`* - you need to quote that. PHP thinks that you're wanting to do some type of math, given IF that is your actual syntax.

Comment: @satya Which error?

Comment: *"but its throwing error."* - Being what? You should have posted what you tried in your question, not in comments.

Comment: @DD77 : ` #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`.

Comment: @chris85 :SELECT * FROM db_user` WHERE mobile REGEXP '+919937229858' this is my query.

Comment: @chris85 : Can you right the full query ?

Comment: `SELECT RIGHT('var', int_length);` --- `SELECT LENGTH(`haystack`) - POSITION('needle' IN REVERSE(`haystack`))` --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `like` and concatenate a wildcard on the column value. Something like:

```
select * from table where ? like concat('%', mobile)
```

I think will do it.

Comment: where is the value `+919937229858` to match.

Comment: The `?` is a placeholder, you bind the value there.

Comment: In a mysql interface it would be `select * from table
where '+919937229858' like concat('%', mobile)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `%` and search whit `LIKE`

`SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE mobile   LIKE '%9937229858' ;`

Comment: @chris85 Yeah I see what you mean now.